# Why did Harley change Joker’s name to Puddin?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, birds-of-prey

In *Birds of Prey: And the Fantabulous Emancipation of One Harley Quinn* (2020), she changed Joker’s name to **Puddin**. Why did she do that?

Comment: Because he's her puddin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All in all, it's just a nickname she gives him, just like some people call their loved ones "honey" or "sweetie".

Out-of-universe, there doesn't seem to be any special reason. It predates the DCEU and the comics, Harley Quinn having debuted in *Batman: The Animated Series*. **When Dr. Harleen Quinzel became Harley Quinn, her very first line contained it**:

> Knock knock, puddin'! Say hello to your new, improved Harley Quinn!

The nickname just stayed afterwards, in various cartoons, comics and movies.

Answer (score 4):

Because that’s her nickname for him. She calls it him several times in *Suicide Squad*, for example:

> **Harley Quinn:** Puddin'! You got all dressed up for me?
>
> **The Joker:** Oh, you know I'd do anything for you.
>
> <sub>*Suicide Squad*</sub>

She even wears a “Puddin” choker.

[image: Harley Quinn face with Puddin choker]